# What is causing the error: Bundler & Minifier error 0: Expected '}'

Tags: javascript, dotnet-build

During a Jenkins build, I am getting the following errors:

> **Bundler: Begin processing bundleconfig.json**
>
> /src/Vizualization/wwwroot/js/datatables-knockout-binding.min.js(29,21,29,21): Bundler & Minifier error 0: Expected '}': ... [/src/Vizualization/Vizualization.csproj]
>
> /src/Vizualization/wwwroot/js/datatables-knockout-binding.min.js(32,33,32,33): Bundler & Minifier error 0: Expected ';' [/src/Vizualization/Vizualization.csproj]
>
> /src/Vizualization/wwwroot/js/datatables-knockout-binding.min.js(32,33,32,33): Bundler & Minifier error 0: Expected expression: : [/src/Vizualization/Vizualization.csproj]
>
> /src/Vizualization/wwwroot/js/datatables-knockout-binding.min.js(46,14,46,14): Bundler & Minifier error 0: Expected '}': ; [/src/Vizualization/Vizualization.csproj]
>
> /src/Vizualization/wwwroot/js/datatables-knockout-binding.min.js(61,5,61,5): Bundler & Minifier error 0: Expected ')': } [/src/Vizualization/Vizualization.csproj]
>
> /src/Vizualization/wwwroot/js/datatables-knockout-binding.min.js(61,6,61,6): Bundler & Minifier error 0: Expected ')': ; [/src/Vizualization/Vizualization.csproj]
>
> /src/Vizualization/wwwroot/js/datatables-knockout-binding.min.js(62,1,62,1): Bundler & Minifier error 0: Syntax error: } [/src/Vizualization/Vizualization.csproj]
>
> /src/Vizualization/wwwroot/js/datatables-knockout-binding.min.js(62,2,62,2): Bundler & Minifier error 0: Expected expression: ) [/src/Vizualization/Vizualization.csproj]
>
> /src/Vizualization/wwwroot/js/datatables-knockout-binding.min.js(62,3,62,3): Bundler & Minifier error 0: Expected expression: ) [/src/Vizualization/Vizualization.csproj]
>
> **Bundler: Done processing bundleconfig.json**

I do not get this when I build locally.  Each are triggered by `dotnet build "Vizualization.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build`

I've looked over the code and do not see any mismatched curly braces.  Because of this and the fact that I cannot reproduce it locally, the MRE is the file, but it is small (see source of datatables-knockout-binding.min.js below)

```
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof require === "function" && typeof exports === "object" && typeof module === "object") {
        factory(require("jquery"), require("knockout"));
    }
    else if (typeof define === "function" && define["amd"]) {
        define(["jquery", "knockout"], factory);
    }
    else {
        factory($, ko);
    }
}(function ($, ko) {
    function getOptions(allBindings) {
        return allBindings.get("tableOptions") || {};
    }

    ko.bindingHandlers.datatable = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            const data = valueAccessor();
            const update = () => {
                const oldTable = $(element).closest("table").DataTable();
                const pageInfo = oldTable.page.info();
                const page = pageInfo.page;
                const pageLength = pageInfo.length;
                const order = oldTable.order();
                const search = oldTable.search();
                oldTable.destroy();
                ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
                const tableOptions = {
                    ...getOptions(allBindings),
                    order,
                    pageLength,
                    deferLoading: true
                };

                if (tableOptions.search) {
                    tableOptions.search.search = search;
                }
                else {
                    tableOptions.search = { search };
                }

                $(element).closest("table")
                    .DataTable(tableOptions)
                    .page(page)
                    .draw();
            };

            data.subscribe(update, null, "arrayChange");
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(element.childNodes, function (node) {
                if (node && node.nodeType !== 1 /*element*/) {
                    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
                }
            });

            ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
            ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
            const tableOptions = getOptions(allBindings);
            $(element).closest("table").DataTable(tableOptions);
            return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
        }
    };
}));
```

Comment: Ever find a reason for this?

Comment: It was not able to find a reason for this.